# Issue taking the date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to take sum of `m1.Price` from m1 by taking a date range as  `m1.tdate between w.adate1 and w.adate2`. The issue is the `m1.price` is not getting calculated correctly. Please review the SQL code.

```
with m1 as 
(
    select sum(c.price) as Price,c.tdate ,c.unit
    from Dim_stocks c 
    group by c.tdate ,c.unit
)
select
    sum(w.total) as cost,
    w.a_time,
    w.unit,
    sum(m1.Price) as price
from Target_Shipment w 
left join m1 on m1.tdate = w.a_time and m1.unit = w.unit
where m1.tdate between cast(DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,w.a_time),0) as date) and w.a_time    
group by w.a_time, w.unit
```

[image: Actual data and Expected Result Set data]

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: Please share some sample code

Comment: "The issue is the m1.price is not getting calculated correctly." - you need to clarify what this means by showing us sample data, expected results and actual results.

Comment: You show source data as a single table, but your query refers to two tables.

Comment: The  value from this "Target_Shipment w" are correct. I am facing issue while calculating "price" from the "m1" table. So have shared data only for m1 table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's not possible to answer without knowing the issue properly. Need sample data for that. But are you trying to get the sum(price) group by date only?

```
with m1 as 
(
    select
        sum(c.price) over (partition by cast(c.tdate-DAY(c.tdate)+1 as date) order by tdate rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Price
        , c.tdate, c.unit
    from Dim_stocks c 
)
select
    sum(w.total) as cost,
    w.a_time,
    w.unit,
    sum(m1.Price) as price
from Target_Shipment w 
left join m1 on m1.tdate = w.a_time and m1.unit = w.unit
where m1.tdate between cast(DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,w.a_time),0) as date) and w.a_time    
group by w.a_time, w.unit
```

Example:

```
create table Dim_stocks(unit varchar(10), tdate date, price float);
insert into Dim_stocks values('MUM' ,'3/1/2021',    2010.3);
insert into Dim_stocks values('MUM' ,'3/1/2021',    4308.49);
insert into Dim_stocks values('MUM' ,'3/2/2021',    2690.75);
insert into Dim_stocks values('MUM' ,'3/5/2021',    3091.4);
insert into Dim_stocks values('COL' ,'2/10/2020',   4025.99);
insert into Dim_stocks values('COL' ,'2/28/2021',   4032.73);
insert into Dim_stocks values('COL' ,'2/1/2021',    3978.79);
insert into Dim_stocks values('COL' ,'11/23/2020',  4157.69);
insert into Dim_stocks values('PUN' ,'11/3/2020',   4032.13);
insert into Dim_stocks values('COL' ,'11/3/2020',   4025.99);
insert into Dim_stocks values('PUN' ,'11/1/2020',   4019.24);

select
    sum(c.price) over (partition by DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, c.tdate))) order by tdate rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Price
    , c.tdate, c.unit
from Dim_stocks c
```

Output:

| Price | tdate | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4025.99 | 2020-02-10 | COL |
| 4019.24 | 2020-11-01 | PUN |
| 8051.37 | 2020-11-03 | PUN |
| 12077.36 | 2020-11-03 | COL |
| 16235.05 | 2020-11-23 | COL |
| 3978.79 | 2021-02-01 | COL |
| 8011.52 | 2021-02-28 | COL |
| 2010.3 | 2021-03-01 | MUM |
| 6318.79 | 2021-03-01 | MUM |
| 9009.54 | 2021-03-02 | MUM |
| 12100.94 | 2021-03-05 | MUM |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2475084298cd43abc5fc76680354ba98)*

Comment: Have mentioned the data.. please check and suggest. Thanks!

Comment: I am grouping by tdate and Unit. But tdate need to be group by taking "FirstDateOfMonth(tdate) to tdate" . Example: if tdate is 17March2020 then price should be "sum(price) for date 1stMarch20 to 17thMarch20"

Comment: got it. will revise my answer shortly

Comment: I have revised my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for the input, much appreciated, but in m1 group by is done on FirstDateOfMonth (tdate) where we need to take range From FirstDateofMonth to tdate. Any input on this pls ?

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: You are most welcome.  If it helped please accept this answer by clicking green check. Best wishes.